# SEER dataset relation between attributes

Tags: classification, dataset

I am working on SEER breast cancer dataset. It is an open source dataset. [SEER dataset](https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/seer-breast-cancer-data). I would like to know what is the relationship between attribute **survival month** and the class attribute ***Status***?

What does it represent using `Survival month`? Is this related to whether the person is alive or dead? Alive and Dead are two categories of **Status** attribute. For example, I found if the survival month is 40 the class label is Alive, at the same time if the survival month is 40 the class label is dead as well.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand of the relationship between survival month and status? Like are you trying to get the likelihood that someone is alive or dead given the survival month? Are you trying to find out how much longer the person is likely to live given the survival month? Are you trying to make some kind of visual to understand the relationship?

Comment: I would like to know the likelihood that someone is alive or dead given the survival month.